# Bubble sort reversing entire list after 3 inputs

Tags: c#, bubble-sort

So I'm trying to sort a list of books that have been added to an array alphabetically however, whenever I input the third book, the list flips and sorts the list in unalphabetical order.

If anyone knows why this is, please comment and let me know, my code is below.

*The sort to determine if two indexes need to be swapped*

```cs
private void bookSort()
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 20; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < bookPTR - 1; x++)
        {
            if (string.Compare(books[x].GStitle, books[x + 1].GStitle) > 0)
            {
                bookSwapRoutine(books[x]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*The swap itself*

```cs
private void bookSwapRoutine(Book book, int x = 0)
{
    string tempString = books[x].GStitle;
    books[x].GStitle = books[x + 1].GStitle;
    books[x + 1].GStitle = tempString;

    int tempInt = books[x].GSisbn;
    books[x].GSisbn = books[x + 1].GSisbn;
    books[x + 1].GSisbn = tempInt;

    tempString = books[x].GSauthor;
    books[x].GSauthor = books[x + 1].GSauthor;
    books[x + 1].GSauthor = tempString;

    tempString = books[x].GSpublisher;
    books[x].GSpublisher = books[x + 1].GSpublisher;
    books[x + 1].GSpublisher = tempString;

    double tempDouble = books[x].GSprice;
    books[x].GSprice = books[x + 1].GSprice;
    books[x + 1].GSprice = tempDouble;

    tempString = books[x].GSdate;
    books[x].GSdate = books[x + 1].GSdate;
    books[x + 1].GSdate = tempString;
}
```

Comment: Not the answer to your question, but why do a swap like this? Why not do something like `Book tempBook = book[x]; book[x] = book[y]; book[y] = tempBook;`?

Comment: @TentMan8001 This task looks rather academic to me, is there a reason why you write sorting algo yourself? Did you consider just to implement a comparer and sort books with it?

Comment: You can even swap with `(book[x], book[y]) = (book[y], book[x])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of this place. That function call always swap books at zero index and first index because of default parameter x = 0.

```
bookSwapRoutine(books[x]);
```

You should call it like.

```
bookSwapRoutine(books[x], x);
```

This will swap books[x] and books[x + 1] for you.

If you want just sort your books by GStitle in alphabeticall order you can call.

```
Array.Sort(books, (x, y) => string.Compare(x.GStitle, y.GStitle, StringComparison.InvariantCulture));
```

Here all code, with correct bubble sort, if it will help you.

```
public static void Main()
{
    var books = new Book[]
    {
        new Book() {GStitle = "E"},
        new Book() {GStitle = "D"},
        new Book() {GStitle = "C"},
        new Book() {GStitle = "B"},
        new Book() {GStitle = "A"}
    };

    Console.WriteLine("Before sort.");
    foreach (var book in books)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(book.GStitle);
    }

    Array.Sort(books, (x, y) => string.Compare(x.GStitle, y.GStitle, StringComparison.InvariantCulture));
    //BookSort(books);

    Console.WriteLine("After sort.");
    foreach (var book in books)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(book.GStitle);
    }
}

public class Book
{
    public string GStitle { get; set; }
}

public static void BookSort(Book[] books)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < books.Length; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < books.Length - 1 - y; x++)
        {
            if (string.Compare(books[x].GStitle, books[x + 1].GStitle, StringComparison.InvariantCulture) > 0)
            {
                var temp = books[x];
                books[x] = books[x + 1];
                books[x + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```